# ¿CRUD con IFRAME de Google Maps? En PHP

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, crud, iframe

Hola estoy tratando de incluir un CRUD de sitios en mi página web ¿Como podría hacer que cuando mis usuarios digiten una dirección en específico, automáticamente se muestre el mapa como en la imagen?

[image: CRUD con iframe]

He intentado insertar el iframe a mi base de datos directamente

[image: Iframe en base de datos mysql]

Y he buscado formas de crear mi propio IFRAME pero no he encontrado la solución ¿Alguna alternativa?

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Puedes incluir en la pregunta cómo usas esos datos en BD para mostrar esa tabla, así otros pueden mostrarte una mejor forma de usar tu código. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre que guardes en la base de datos solo la longitud y la latitud de la dirección.

Entonces en el front end (la tabla de la primera imagen) escribas el iframe y le insertes la logitud y la latitud que le corresponda. No se exactamente como esta ese iframe, si lo pudieses copiar entero te podria dar más detalles.

**Edito:**

```
<iframe src="google.com/maps/…" width="auto" height="auto" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"></iframe>
```

Podrias guardar el atributo src en la base de datos y despues agregarlo al iframe al cargar la tabla. Es lo mismo que te he explicado con la latitud y la longitud pero con la url.

Saludos

Comment: <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d15865.95207615446!2d-75.58287413022461!3d6.199163599999994!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x8e468287861a634f%3A0xa56a11518e7401c6!2sLeonisa%20Oviedo!5e0!3m2!1ses!2sco!4v1643921341964!5m2!1ses!2sco" width="auto" height="auto" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"></iframe>